# How do I apply something like the double slash notation but not at the end of line?

Tags: functions

```
f[x_] = x^2;
Scan[Print[f[#]] &, {1, 2, 3}]
```

I want to do something like this, but I don't want to type so many brackets.
I'd like to have something like

```
f[x_] = x^2;
Scan[f[#] //Print &, {1, 2, 3}]
```

But this doesn't work. What's the correct symbol/method, to pipe the output of f[#] to Print ?

Sorry I googled "mathematica pipe output" but I don't think I'm using the correct keywords. But linux users have the terminology of "piping".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To obtain the "pipeline" style with the data at the beginning of the expression, we can write:

```
{1, 2, 3} // Scan[f /* Print]
```

[image: printed output]

This combines `f` and `Print` into a single function using [/*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html) (*right composition*) and then uses the [operator form](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionCompositionAndOperatorForms.html) of [Scan](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html) to lift that function so that it operates upon lists.

This composed function is then applied to the list `{1, 2, 3}` using the postfix notation [//](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Postfix.html).

We can dispense with brackets altogether by adding some [infix notation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infix.html)...

```
f /* Print ~Scan~ {1, 2, 3}
```

... but perhaps this is taking it too far (and the initial value is no longer at the start of the pipeline).

Another way to get a similar visual result would be to write:

```
{1, 2, 3} // Map[f] // Column
```

[image: columnar output]

If you are interested in combining operators in a concatenative style, you might want to check out [Query](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html).  For example:

```
{1, 2, 3} // Query[Column, f]
```

[image: query output]

Answer (score 9):

The problem, as usual, is precedence. You need to use parenthesis to group expressions. The code

```
Scan[ (#^2 // Print) &, {1, 2, 3}]
```

will now do what you want. Your reference to "mathematica pipe output" is a good idea. You can think of`//`as the Mathematica equivalent to the Unix pipe symbol `|` or better yet the Forth postfix notation for executing "words" which use the data stack to operate on. In fact, Mathematica itself has an "evaluation stack"  accessed using the`Stack[]`and related functions.

Answer (score 8):

These are different ways to write the same:

```
(f[#] // Print) &

Print@f[#] &

Print[f[#]] &
```

`f[#] // Print &` is parsed as `(f[#]) // (Print &)`—mind the precendence.

The following are also effectively equivalent (though they denote a different expression):

```
Print @* f

f /* Print
```

See [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html), [`RightComposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html)

Comment: Use `;` to suppress output of `Null`s: `Print@*f /@ Range@3;`

Answer (score 8):

Another option by using the true name of [`&`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html):

```
f[x_] = x^2;
Scan[f[#] //Print //Function, {1, 2, 3}]
```